# can you help me to fix this code about bubble sort?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

i am newbie, i don't know how to fix it?
i don't know how to call function void bubblesort

```
 #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = n - 1; j > i; j--)
            if (a[j] < a[j - 1])
                swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
}

int main() {
    int a[]={1,4,7,2,6,5,3,9,8,10};
    bubbleSort(a[], sizeof(a));
    for (size_t i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<< a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell more about your problem ? Is nothing shown ? Did the bubble sort don't do anything ? Did your program crash ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: the second parameter to `bubblesort()` shouldn't be `sizeof(a)`. It should number of elements

Comment: @Caleth Not `sizeof(a)`, but `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`.

Comment: Change `bubbleSort(a[], sizeof(a));` to `bubbleSort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));`

Comment: What makes you think that the code needs fixing? Please report the symptoms and other observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an array as an argument into a function, you simply pass it as if it were a variable. In this case, simply just `a` would do. This is because [arrays "decay" into pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer) so `a` is a "pointer" to your array.

In addition, I recommend dividing by the `sizeof(a[0])` to get the full length as the [sizeof function returns the size in bytes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

```cpp
bubbleSort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to call the function passing `a` and its size would be as shown below. There is no need to have the square brackets `[]` when passing `a` to the function.

Additionally, for passing the size of the array as the second argument, you can either use `std::size` which is available with `C++17` or use the expression `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]` also shown below.

```
//----------v---------------->no need for the square brackets [] 
bubbleSort(a, std::size(a)); //use std::size(a) with C++17
```

Or

```
bubbleSort(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]); //works with all C++ versions
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gQGPeWESa)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass a pointer and a length, you could pass a reference to the array.

You also don't need `[]` to name `a`;

```
template<size_t n>
void bubbleSort(int (&a)[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (a[j] < a[j - 1])
                std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={1,4,7,2,6,5,3,9,8,10};
    bubbleSort(a);
    for (size_t i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me why we have "template<size_t n>" in this code please?

Comment: @longtimenoseee the size of an array is part of it's type, so you need a template to handle any size of array